# JGIT Pull NoHeadException

Tags: java, eclipse, git, egit, jgit

When is try to execute the following method (uses JGIT library)

```
 private void pullRepo() throws  IOException,GitAPIException, WrongRepositoryStateException, InvalidConfigurationException, DetachedHeadException, InvalidRemoteException, CanceledException, RefNotFoundException, NoHeadException{
            Git  git = new Git(localRepo);
            git.pull().call();
    }
```

I get the following runtime exception:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.NoHeadException: Pull on repository without HEAD currently not supported
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.PullCommand.call(PullCommand.java:161)
```

Does someone know how to solve this?
The localRepo I use is the same as I use for the cloneRepository method ,which works perfectly.

thanks,
bgvv1983

Comment: I see the same when I try to add something like this to my JGit snippe collection at https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook, but failed with the same error, seems like JGit has some limitation here.

Comment: I've also posted the question on the Eclipse Egit forum.
Hopefully someone has a solution there

Comment: Does the repo have a HEAD reference (check with `git rev-parse HEAD`)?

Comment: @robinst I get an answer like 99c4b2aff699ad0928b33weab6badf64f7a827356

Comment: What does the following print?: `cat .git/HEAD`

Comment: @robinst ref: refs/heads/master

Comment: Are you sure you are using the repo instance is correctly obtained? Could you include the code for it in the question?

Comment: `private void pullRepo() throws NoHeadException{
    Git  git = new Git(localRepo);
                    PullCommand cmd = git.pull();
                    cmd.call();
            }`

I left out most of the exceptions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Think I found my mistake.
was on the wrong level in my project folder.

I was at  the ../project (which works in your shell)  level in stead of ../project/.git level.